# How to check if multiple elements are present in a list in Python using operator/in-built functions?

Tags: python

If this returns true,

```
>>> "en" in "english"
True
```

Why doesn't this?

```
>>> [1,2] in [1,2,3,4]
False
```

Comment: The `in` operation on strings searches for substrings. The `in` operation on most other sequences and collections matches a single element.

Comment: @ggorlen So why does it work differently for strings? Is there any similar way to emulate this behavior with strings, since both are sequences

Comment: `"en" in list("english")` or `"en" in iter("english")` will behave like the latter, matching only elements of the iterable which is the string.

Comment: @HenloWald you can write your own search function that implements the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings and lists are simply different. `a in b` is implemented by `b.__contains__(a)`. `__contains__` is defined on a class-by-class basis.

When `b` is a `str`,
`str.__contains__(b, a)` returns true if `a` is a substring of `b`.

When `b` is a `list`,
`list.__contains__(b, a)` returns true if `b` is an *element* of `a`.

In order to check if a list `a` is a subsequence of a list `b`, you could try something like

```
any(a == b[i:i+len(a)] for i, _ in enumerate(b[:-len(a)+1]))
```

Comment: So I'll need my own manual implementation to search for multiple elements in other sequences...eg. a for loop that checks for all elements until an element is not found to return False, else True...there is no inbuilt method/operator to emulate the same behavior

Answer (score -2):

This will give you true: >>>`1 and 2 in [1,2,3,4]`
But [1,2] means that you are checking for the list [1,2] in the list [1,2,3,4] which is not there.
It would be true if your list was `[[1,2],3,4]`.

```
>>> [1,2] in [[1,2],3,4]
True
```

Comment: Ok wow, now that's interesting...Is there any way to do it for dynamic number of elements?

Comment: `1 and 2 in [1,2,3,4]` just burns my retinas.

Comment: `and` doesn't work like that. Try `11 and 2 in [1,2,3,4]` -> `True`. It's equivalent to `11 and (2 in [1,2,3,4])`, where `11` is truthy since it's non-zero.

Comment: @wjandrea I corrected it it just slipped of my mind. sorry.